# BR can not be resolved in Android Databinding

Tags: android, data-binding

I am using Android Data binding but BR can not be resolved 
here is my dummy view model

I have enabled data binding in my app gradle the

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

The gradle-wrapper.properties having data:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Here is my View Model

```
public class DummyViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    private int mSomeValue = 0;
    public void setValue(int value) {
        mSomeValue = value;
        //Here BR can not be resolved
        notifyPropertyChanged(com.something.myapplication.BR.positive);
    }

    @Bindable
    public boolean isPositive() {

        return mSomeValue > 0;
    }
}
```

Here the classPath of Project gradle

```
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Android Studio `version: 3.4`

Answer (score 1):

If your XML is valid try cleaning and rebuilding. It can sometimes take a while for AS to reconcile the data bindings. If it still doesn't run it's likely you have an error in your code elsewhere.

XML should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.something.myapplication.DummyViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.positive ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            android:src="@drawable/something"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: I haven't designed the view yet there is only one actvity_main.xml and which is contain of a textview of having text "Hello World". I have checked the it's xml it has no error

Comment: The binding is only created when there's something to bind it to. Since you haven't declared your view model in any XML, no binding exists yet. Try adding the xml I provided into your `activity_main.xml`

Comment: I am only developing back-end for my app not the front-end. To bind a ViewModel with a view(xml) it will be in later stage

Comment: There is no need to use the `notifyPropertyChanged` method if there is no UI to notify. You can either put in dummy XML to create the binding or you can come back to this step once it's created.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your project to android x and then remove old  BR class and add BR class from below package
import androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR

Answer (score 0):

This answer is late but it might help someone like it helped me

Delete the 'Build' file and 'Rebuild Project' (Build-> click Rebuild Project)